# Facebook comment data empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a Facebook Graph API access token in which I've requested read_stream and user_status access. When I try to get comment data for myself:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/comments?access_token=[MyToken]

I get a blank piece of Json back:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I do have recent comments on my stream. Shouldn't they show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=[MyToken]

-michael

Comment: It's a little different, as I just wanted the comments and I think this will give me photos and stuff, too, but that actually works better. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it seems what I was referring to as a "comment" is actually a "status". That explains why there was no data.